# Does the Altium model of this relay match the datasheet? TX2-5V - Solved - No

Tags: pcb-design, altium, datasheet

Altium offers this model when a Manufacturer part search is done for a Panasonic TX2-5V, notice that in the un-energized state pins 8 and 9 as well as 3 and 4 are contacted in the model.

The datasheet has the un-energize state of 9 and 10 being contacted. I want to make sure that I'm not mis-understanding something in the datasheet but I feel that the Altium model is incorrect.

https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/cdn/e/control/relay/signal/catalog/mech_eng_tx.pdf

Am I seeing it correctly?

From the Altium model

[image]

From the Panasonic datasheet

[image]

Comment: Looks to be incorrect. Check the footprint pin numbering too, the "error" might be corrected there, or not. Never trust a model you have not made yourself and verified.

Comment: The foot print pin numbering matches the datasheet. I've reported the issue to Altium, I'm sure it will be corrected by time AD v26 comes out  - Thanks!

Comment: If you have an answer to your question you should post it as an answer, and then accept the answer (click the check-mark). Adding "Solved" to the title just isn't how we do it around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the datasheet is incorrect